# convert (Translate ) from one sql syntax to another (from mssql to oracle,h2...)

Tags: sql

The application that I started working on uses several databases with different SQL syntax for different clients (MsSQL,MySQL, oracle,h2 for JUnit tests...). Updating all databases(adding a new table) is a manual task.
I have tried several free tools that I found online to do the conversion from one syntax to another
http://www.sqlines.com/online
https://www.jooq.org/translate/
but they don't work well for triggers and datatypes.
My question is what would be the best way to automate this process of maintaining multiple databases for a single app, write SQL in just one syntax and convert to all others?
It is an older project so I cant use hibernate to generate the SQL for me.

Comment: write ISO SQL queries and put as much as possible stored procedures logic to the application level.

Comment: You could manage your schema migration tool like Liquibase which supports a DBMS independent XML format. For running SQL statements you will have to create some kind of abstraction layer (e.g. "data access objects" that have specific implementations for each DBMS product if needed)

Answer (score 0):

**Try This:**
*https://www.jooq.org/translate/*
OR
There are a number of database tools that help migrating data from one to another database, for example:

- Flyway
- SQuirreL DB Copy Plugin